# How to correctly use the builtin `MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX` for `std::complex<double>` with Boost.MPI?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, boost-mpi

I want to transfer a large amount of `std::complex<double>` numbers using Boost.MPI. In the [Boost.MPI tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.performance_optimizations) it is explained that

> To obtain optimal performance for small fixed-length data types not
>   containing any pointers it is very important to mark them using the
>   type traits of Boost.MPI and Boost.Serialization.
>
> It was already discussed that fixed length types containing no
>   pointers can be using as `is_mpi_datatype`, e.g.:
>
> ```
> namespace boost { namespace mpi {   template <>   struct
> is_mpi_datatype<gps_position> : mpl::true_ { }; } }
> ```
>
> or the equivalent macro
>
> ```
> BOOST_IS_MPI_DATATYPE(gps_position)
> ```

The [documentation of `is_mpi_datatype`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/is_mpi_datatype.html) gives another example:

> [...] To do so, first make
>   the data type Serializable (using the Boost.Serialization library);
>   then, specialize the `is_mpi_datatype` trait for the `point` type so that
>   it will `derive mpl::true_`:
>
> ```
> namespace boost { namespace mpi {
>   template<> struct is_mpi_datatype<point>
>     : public mpl::true_ { };
> } }
> ```

When I try exactly that to optimize performance [Options (A) or (B) in my attempt below], I observe that Boost.MPI does not use the builtin MPI datatype `MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX` nor does it map to the `MPI_SUM` operation [assertions (3) and (4) in my attempt below]. Moreover, enabling one of (A) or (B) as well as disabling assertions (3) and (4) yields a segmentation fault at runtime.

In [some source file of Boost.MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/mpi/datatype.hpp) I have found an undocumented(?) macro called `BOOST_MPI_DATATYPE` which does the right thing, but is marked with the comment `/// INTERNAL ONLY`.

Before implementing this ugly hack(?) I would like to ask: **What is the intended way to tell Boost.MPI to use the builtin `MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX` datatype for `std::complex<double>`?**

```
#include <complex>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/complex.hpp>

// tested with GCC 6.2.0, OpenMPI 2.0.1, boost 1.62.0
// mpic++ -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization boost-mpi-complex.cpp

using dcomplex = std::complex<double>;
using dcplus = std::plus<dcomplex>;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// How to pass assertions (1) to (5) below?
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// (A): documented, but fails assertions (2) and (3)
// if (2) and (3) are removed with this OPTION: segmentation fault at runtime
//BOOST_IS_MPI_DATATYPE(dcomplex)

// (B): documented, but same problems as (A)
namespace boost::mpi {
//template<> struct is_mpi_datatype<dcomplex> : boost::mpl::true_ {};
}

// (C): works, but not documented(?) and has `INTERNAL ONLY` comment in source
namespace boost::mpi {
//BOOST_MPI_DATATYPE(dcomplex, MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, complex);
}

// (D): works, equivalent to (C)
// BUT if `is_mpi_complex_datatype` is specialized without `get_mpi_datatype`
// then compilation is fine with all assertions, but running yields segfault
namespace boost::mpi {
//template<> inline MPI_Datatype get_mpi_datatype<dcomplex>(const dcomplex&) {
//  return MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX;
//}
//template<> struct is_mpi_complex_datatype<dcomplex> : boost::mpl::true_ {};
}

// optional; works as expected for assertion (4)
namespace boost::mpi {
template<> struct is_commutative<dcplus, dcomplex> : mpl::true_ {};
}

// If these assertions are removed and none of (A) to (D) is activated then
// everything works as expected, but I would like to optimize serialization
static_assert(boost::mpi::is_mpi_datatype<dcomplex>{});                   // (1)
static_assert(boost::mpi::is_mpi_builtin_datatype<dcomplex>{});           // (2)

static_assert(boost::mpi::is_mpi_op<dcplus, dcomplex>{});                 // (3)
static_assert(boost::mpi::is_commutative<dcplus, dcomplex>{});            // (4)

static_assert(boost::serialization::is_bitwise_serializable<dcomplex>{}); // (5)

int main() {
  boost::mpi::environment env{};
  boost::mpi::communicator world{};

  constexpr size_t N = 4;

  dcomplex data[N]{};
  if(0 == world.rank()) {
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) data[i] = dcomplex{double(i), 0.0};
  }
  if(1 == world.rank()) {
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) data[i] = dcomplex{0.0, double(N+i)};
  }

  all_reduce(world, boost::mpi::inplace(data), N, dcplus{});

  if(0 == world.rank()) {
    for(auto&& x : data) std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: option (D) looks correct to me. What is the problem with that one? assertion (2) should always fail, since complex<double> is not builtin, and you shouldn't mess with the boost internals. I expect (3) should also fail, since you are providing a user defined operator. This should be fine nonetheless.

Comment: To me, (D) feels as `INTERNAL ONLY` as (C). Moreover, the [Boost.MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/is_mpi_builtin_datatype.html) documentation states that "In general, users should not need to specialize this trait.".

The [MPI specification 3.1](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) lists `MPI_CXX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX` and `MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX` as "Predefined MPI datatypes".

Finally, `std::plus` [is said to map to MPI_PLUS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.tutorial.c_mapping.t5).

Comment: Correction: std::plus [is said to map to MPI_SUM](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.tutorial.c_mapping.t5).

Comment: Since boost doesn't properly supply these builtin datatypes, I think you should just define it as if you had a class/struct with a custom MPI_Datatype. I.e. specialize get_mpi_datatype to return the corresponding MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX. This will still use custom operators for the reduction, but this should be the same efficiency as the builtin reduction MPI_SUM (in my experience at least).